# How do I make a PageView allow scrolling when mouse is detected

Tags: flutter, debugging

I have an web app that uses PageView to allow swiping through pages. I would like to somehow add the ability to scroll when a mouse is detected so that its more intuitive and doesn't confuse the user. I've been stuck trying to use a listener and can't seem to figure out. could someone help me figure out how I could do this?

[Click to view gif of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6ca4.gif)

Here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

int currentPage = 0;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final PageController ctrl = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8);

  @override
  Widget build(
    BuildContext context,
  ) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Builder(
      builder: (context) => Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxWidth: 1000,
            maxHeight: 2000,
          ),
          child: PageView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            controller: ctrl,
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.green,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                          blurRadius: 20,
                          offset: Offset(1, 1))
                    ]),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                          blurRadius: 20,
                          offset: Offset(1, 1))
                    ]),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                          blurRadius: 20,
                          offset: Offset(1, 1))
                    ]),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.red,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                          blurRadius: 20,
                          offset: Offset(1, 1))
                    ]),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )));
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Update: here is what I have so far. I thought this might work but it didn't

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

int currentPage = 0;

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final PageController pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8);

  bool pageIsScrolling = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Builder(
                builder: (context) => Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      // to detect swipe
                      onPanUpdate: (details) {
                        _onScroll(details.delta.dy * -1);
                      },
                      child: Listener(
                        // to detect scroll
                        onPointerSignal: (pointerSignal) {
                          if (pointerSignal is PointerScrollEvent) {
                            _onScroll(pointerSignal.scrollDelta.dy);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          constraints: BoxConstraints(
                            maxWidth: 1000,
                            maxHeight: 2000,
                          ),
                          child: PageView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            controller: pageController,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                                          blurRadius: 20,
                                          offset: Offset(1, 1))
                                    ]),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                    color: Colors.blue,
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                                          blurRadius: 20,
                                          offset: Offset(1, 1))
                                    ]),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                    color: Colors.orange,
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                                          blurRadius: 20,
                                          offset: Offset(1, 1))
                                    ]),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                                          blurRadius: 20,
                                          offset: Offset(1, 1))
                                    ]),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )))));
  }

  void _onScroll(double offset) {
    if (pageIsScrolling == false) {
      pageIsScrolling = true;
      if (offset > 0) {
        pageController
            .nextPage(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.easeInOut)
            .then((value) => pageIsScrolling = false);

        print('scroll down');
      } else {
        pageController
            .previousPage(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.easeInOut)
            .then((value) => pageIsScrolling = false);
        print('scroll up');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use the https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html as a parent to PageView.

Answer (score 1):

Added the MouseRegion as a parent for your PageView and find the mouse enter and exit notification to do your logics

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _enterCounter = 0;
  int _exitCounter = 0;
  double x = 0.0;
  double y = 0.0;

  void _incrementEnter(PointerEvent details) {
    setState(() {
      _enterCounter++;
    });
  }

  void _incrementExit(PointerEvent details) {
    setState(() {
      _exitCounter++;
    });
  }

  void _updateLocation(PointerEvent details) {
    setState(() {
      x = details.position.dx;
      y = details.position.dy;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size(300.0, 200.0)),
      child: MouseRegion(
        onEnter: _incrementEnter,
        onHover: _updateLocation,
        onExit: _incrementExit,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('You have entered or exited this box this many times:'),
              Text(
                '$_enterCounter Entries\n$_exitCounter Exits',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'The cursor is here: (${x.toStringAsFixed(2)}, ${y.toStringAsFixed(2)})',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's help you requirement, please mark as correct answer. Thanks advance